# Content Search webpart with sort/query using CSOM

Tags: client-object-model, content-search-web-part

How can we add a Content By Search webpart using CSOM when we want to use a custom query (in SP2013)?

Would there be an easy way?

For example, could we just

1. Import the web part
2. Set DataProviderJSON.QueryTemplate property

and be happy

For example, this article suggest we could just update QueryTemplate in DataProviderJSON property: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint2013learnings/archive/2013/10/24/update-search-query-of-content-by-search-webpart-through-csom.aspx. However, opening the query settings of the web part seems to clear the change.

In order to test this I imported the webpart first with minimal settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ContentBySearchWebPart, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">My Content Search Web Part</property>
        <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Then I changed the web part in UI and exported and imported successfully. However, the web part is pretty complicated, especially the DataProvideerJSON property:

```
{
    "Properties": {
        "ListId": "aa6114c1-3159-45c9-b3cc-27b6b72520fb",
        "ListItemId": 2,
        "UpdateLinksForCatalogItems": true,
        "EnableStacking": true
    },
    "PropertiesJson": "{\"ListId\":\"aa6114c1-3159-45c9-b3cc-27b6b72520fb\",\"ListItemId\":2,\"UpdateLinksForCatalogItems\":true,\"EnableStacking\":true}",
    "SourceID": "8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89",
    "QueryGroupName": "e8a2dac3-1cdc-484d-87a1-7db9bde15e30",
    "QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl": "sitesearch://webroot",
    "IgnoreQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl": false,
    "SourceName": "Local SharePoint Results",
    "SourceLevel": "Ssa",
    "CollapseSpecification": "",
    "QueryTemplate": "(IsDocument:\"True\")",
    "FallbackSort": [
        {
            "p": "LastModifiedTime",
            "d": 1
        }
    ],
    "FallbackSortJson": "[{\"p\":\"LastModifiedTime\",\"d\":1}]",
    "RankRules": null,
    "RankRulesJson": "null",
    "AsynchronousResultRetrieval": false,
    "SendContentBeforeQuery": true,
    "BatchClientQuery": true,
    "FallbackLanguage": -1,
    "FallbackRankingModelID": "",
    "EnableStemming": true,
    "EnablePhonetic": false,
    "EnableNicknames": false,
    "EnableInterleaving": false,
    "EnableQueryRules": true,
    "EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty": false,
    "HitHighlightedMultivaluePropertyLimit": -1,
    "IgnoreContextualScope": true,
    "ScopeResultsToCurrentSite": false,
    "TrimDuplicates": false,
    "ClientType": "",
    "UpdateAjaxNavigate": true,
    "SummaryLength": 180,
    "DesiredSnippetLength": 90,
    "PersonalizedQuery": false,
    "FallbackRefinementFilters": null,
    "IgnoreStaleServerQuery": false,
    "RenderTemplateId": "DefaultDataProvider",
    "AlternateErrorMessage": null,
    "Title": ""
}
```

However, I am not interested in these extra values, but only want to set the query. How can this be done in some reasonable & easy way? Do we need to set ListIds and other complicated properties - and how could SharePoint do it for us?

**Update**
Importing seems to work fine when just setting the DataProviderJSON.Properties and DataProviderJSON.PropertiesJson as empty. What is then the meaning of the properties under them? Can they just be omitted and would this be the best practice way?